# How to use delete_object using Generic views in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have this code:

`book_model = {'model' : Book}`

`(r'^book/delete/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', create_update.delete_object, book_model`

But it gives me error:

```
delete_object() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
```

Now docs say that:

> All the arguments are the same as for
>   the update object view, as is the
>   context; the template name for this
>   view is
>   /_confirm_delete.html.

Now I am confused what should I write in that template. Do I need to create the post form for `yes` and `no`  and what should be the `action attribute` of that form?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which documentation you are looking at, but the [actual documentation for `delete_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-create-update-delete-object) clearly shows what the missing argument is - `post_delete_redirect`.

Comment: After doing that i get error `books/book_confirm_delete.html` does not exists . This is what i was talking about